# Wrap words with &nbsp in span

Tags: javascript, regex

I need wrap words with &nbsp in span, for example:

```
<p>Word word&nbsp;and&nbsp;word2? But word word&nbsp;to.</p>
```

Should become:

```
<p>Word <span>word&nbsp;and&nbsp;word2?</span> But word <span>word&nbsp;to.</span></p>
```

I wanna do this with regular expression in JavaScript.

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: What should&thinsp;this give?

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this https://regex101.com/r/bUflp4/2 for you regex. Be care however, it won't accept tag inside others.

---

For the replacement, you can use something like this

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("text-to-replace");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var innerHTML = elements.item(i).innerHTML;

    var regex = new RegExp('([^ ,<]*&nbsp;[^ ,<\/]*)', 'ig');
    var text  = innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span class="span-to-add">$1</span>');
    elements.item(i).innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.span-to-add {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text-to-replace">Word word&nbsp;and&nbsp;word2? But word word&nbsp;to.</p>
  <p class="text-to-replace">&nbsp;word this is an&nbsp;<a href="#">example</a></p>
  <p class="text-to-replace">this is&nbsp;another&nbsp; example</p>
</div>
```